# Iteration through json object with API

Tags: javascript, json, api, xmlhttprequest, javascript-objects

In the table needs to show the data for the some users that are linked from the link in the request.Im getting the XMLRequest first and setting RequestHeader.

In function show i am creating th tags for the users for their attributes.I have a issue with users data that needs to be shown below.I can't figure out whats the problem with printing undefined in td tags.

The prototype of the data is Object.

```html
<script>

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("GET","https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/user")

    request.setRequestHeader("app-id","6176d770ceedfe1a52297285");

    request.onreadystatechange = async function () {

        var json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        var f = json.data;

        var obj = Object.assign({},json.data);
        console.log(obj);
        show(obj);

    }
    request.send();

    function show(data) {
        let tab =
            `<tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Picture</th>
         </tr>`;


        for (var r in data) {

            tab += `<tr>
    <td>${r.id} </td>
    <td>${r.title}</td>
    <td>${r.firstName}</td>
    <td>${r.lastName}</td>
    <td>${r.picture}</td>


</tr>`;
        }
        document.getElementById("employees").innerHTML = tab;
    }
    // show(data);

</script>


<h1>Registered Employees</h1>
<table id="employees"></table>
</body>
```

Comment: `r` is the array index, not the array element. Use `for (var r of data)` to iterate over the elements.

Answer (score 0):

More easy to do that with a fetch

```js
const tEmployees = document.querySelector('#employees tbody')  

fetch('https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/user', { method: 'GET', headers: { 'app-id': '6176d770ceedfe1a52297285' } })
.then( res => res.json())
.then( employees =>
  {
  employees.data.forEach(emp => 
    {
    let newRow = tEmployees.insertRow()
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = emp.id
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = emp.title
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = emp.firstName
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = emp.lastName
    newRow.insertCell().innerHTML   = `<img src="${emp.picture}" alt="${emp.firstName} – ${emp.lastName}" width="72" height="72">` 
    })
  })
.catch((error) =>  console.error('Error:', error) )
```

```css
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 14px;
  }
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  }
td,th  {
  padding    : .2em .8em;
  border     : 1px solid darkblue;
  }
thead { 
  background-color: steelblue;
  }
```

```html
<h1>Registered Employees</h1>
<table id="employees">
  <thead>
    <tr> <th>Id</th> <th>Title</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th>Picture</th> </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertRow')
    at index2.html:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at index2.html:17

Comment: @КристијанНиколоски I thought you were not interested in my answer. Otherwise, ok, the error you find means to me that you have not changed your HTML for corresponding on my snippet